# Get all tiles in a box between 4 coordinate points: Find all x y values for different z values

Tags: swift, math, gis, openstreetmap, trigonometry

I'm trying to cache map tiles for offline use through MapKit and tiles from openstreetmap.org

- How can I get all the tiles in a box between 4 coordinate points?
- In other words: 
  **How can I find all `Y` and `X` points for different `Z` levels within 4 coordinates forming a box?**

All my searches lead to people saying you can't store maps offline and point to paid services. But storing/caching tiles for offline use is actually stupidly easy:

```
// Custom map overlays
class OpenMapOverlay: MKTileOverlay {

    // grabs the tile for the current x y z
    override func url(forTilePath path: MKTileOverlayPath) -> URL {

        if TileMaster.shared.tileExistsLocally(for: path) {
            // return local URL
            return TileMaster.shared.getPath(for: TileMaster.shared.getFileName(for: path))
        } else {
            // Otherwise download and save
            TileMaster.shared.saveTile(for: path)
            // If you're downloading and saving, then you could also just pass the url to renderer
            let tileUrl = "https://tile.openstreetmap.org/\(path.z)/\(path.x)/\(path.y).png"
            return URL(string: tileUrl)!
        }
    }
}
```

the above code is telling the Map's tile renderer where it should get the tile for the X Y Z from. If it's stored, return the path to local storage (in document directory); otherwise, return the OpenStreetMap URL for the tile, and store the tile for next time.

- I need the math to get all X Y Z points of interest to store them before the tile is visited.

Comment: Of course it is possible to store maps / tiles offline. Did you already take a look at https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames?

Comment: Thanks! hadn't found it. Very helpful formulas.